# .NET Framework dependency tree

Tags: c#, nuget

I need to generate a dependency tree (or at least a dependency list) of .NET Framework 4.6.1. project. I need to deliver such a list to the legal department of my company.
It's a Windows application with package.config file. I am looking for a command which I can run in terminal to generate dependency tree or list, excluding .NET 4.6.1 runtime packages.

I was trying `dotnet list package`, but it works only with .NET Core.

I was also trying to run combinations of NuGet commands: `Get-Content`, `Get-Package`, `Select`. The output I receive is different from what I see in Visual Studio:

[image: console output]

[image]

I would like to see the similar output in my console to Visual Studio window. How do you think I can solve my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make `dotnet list package` and all the .NET CLI running fine with .NET Framework by converting your project to the new project format.

It will be much easier when you already converted to PackageReference and you can easily do it by notepad style editing your .csproj file.

I found this helpful in the past: https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/

Comment: once converted your .csproj to  new project format (targeting .NET Framework) it runs fine and you can check your Nuget dependencies in a nice tree view in VS as well.

Comment: Thank you, it indeed helped. Do you know if I can exclude from `dotnet list package` transitive dependencies that come from .NET Framework itself? I mean generally `System.` and `Microsoft.` namespaces, but I don't want to exclude these namespaces once they have to be installed explicitely as project dependency.

Comment: @michail_w did you try `dotnet list package  --include-transitive | WHERE { $_ -notmatch ' System.| Microsoft.'}` in Powershell?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It works fine. However, it can be false positive. Anyone can create a System. or Microsoft. package which will become my transitive dependency, but it won't be part of the .NET Framework itself. I don't want to miss that out. I agree it's an edge case, but I won't be surprised if it ever happens.

Comment: are we talking of hacking or real world developing?! Take a chance and try to publish a System.Michail.Util Pagacke on Nuget...

Comment: In fact we are talking of real world examples. Large companies have their own artifactories created inside their networks. I mean solutions like JFrog or Nexus. These usually work like real world package managers proxies. "A command line nuget" makes requests only to these artifactories directly, and these proxies make requests to real NuGet once they can't satisfy requests from "the cache".

Usually, such artifactories allow to publish a package into any namespace. And yes, it can be a real problem in huge corporations.

Comment: can you define, what exactly you are missing? you want to see only the content of the "top level" dependencies you see in the migration UI?

Comment: I am missing a PGP signature which I can verify based on trusted list of public keys.

Comment: ok I see, but that is way beyond the scope of you initial question.

Comment: Many thanks for "dotnet list package --include-transitive" !!! Really usedful command!